# How do I show through *ngIf

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to trigger the *ngIf function through my home.component.ts.

html

```
<GridLayout class="page">
<GridLayout row="0" rows="*, 2*, *">
    <GridLayout width="57%" row="0" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
       <button (click)="test()" text="testbutton"></button>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout class="carousel-item-circle" row="1" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
        <label class="fa carousel-item-icon" text="&#xf130;" textWrap="true"></label>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout *ngIf="testi" width="49%" row="2" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
        <Label class="text-color-blue opensans-regular carousel-item-desc" text="Mikrofon zum Sprechen antippen." textWrap="true"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

ts

```
public vibrator = new Vibrate();
    public testi = true;

    constructor(private page: Page) {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
        this.page.addCss(".page-content { background: #000000");
    }

    vibrate(){
        this.vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    }

    test(){
        this.testi = !this.testi;
    }
```

It seems so simple but it doesnt work.
Is there something i missed?

Comment: The code you've provided is a mess. Can you show us some valid HTML in which you used `*ngIf`?

Comment: yeah, the code is messy. Anyway it seems ok. Maybe you check the console to see if any errors occur? I think your code is failing for some other reason that why the test() is not executed

Comment: Yeah I hope this is helpsome.

Comment: The console doesn't provide any errors. I run it through an android simulator.
And i can't debug.

Comment: do you use default ChangeDetectionStrategy ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the variable true/false on click

Write in Your HTML file

```
<button (click)="test()">Click</button>
<span *ngIf="testi">NG IF</span>
```

Write in Your TS file
First Declare testi as

```
testi = false

test(){
   testi = true;
}
```

Using *ngIf you can show the element whenever it is true or not empty, if it is false or empty then it will not display element in browser

Hope this will solve your problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript Button uses `tap` not `click`. So in your code `test()` is never called.

```
<button (tap)="test()" text="testbutton"></button>
```

Refer the [getting started guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/introduction) and go through the available UI components to understand the core differences.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to do that!